# Long Stay Visitor Visa/income from Youtube monetisation

Tags: visa, france

### Long Stay Visitor Visa

I think I understand it correctly. When applying for such a visa, the applicant must attest that they will not seek work or earn an income whilst remaining in France under the auspices of such a visa.

### YouTube Monetisation

If you set up a YouTube channel, it is possible to monetise it and dependent on certain factors, obtain an income from the channel activity.

### Questions

Is there an official reference paper available which specifically outlines whether such an activity is legally allowable in France given the existence of a Long Stay Visitor Visa (including the required signing of an attestation sur l'honneur in support of the application) if the activity only commenced after arrival in France.

It is noted that under French law, there is an obligation imposed on online platforms under the French Finance Act 2016 on users residing in France or selling products or providing services in France.

Fin. Act. 2016, no.2015-1785, 29 Dec. 2015, Art. 87.  
Amended Fin. Act. 2016, no.2016-1918, 29 Dec. 2016, Art. 24

These references would suggest that the fisc would automatically be notified of the income in respect to each tax year (Jan - Dec) and might raise a red flag for the fisc if the taxpayer has not declared it.

---

The main questions are, is monetisation from YouTube regarded as employment for the purposes of the visa conditions and if so, is there a limit after which a tax declaration by the taxpayer is required to declare it?

Since content producers often spend significant amounts on equipment (cameras, microphones, cloud storage etc) are such costs allowable as an expense against such income even if the tax payer is not formally a micro-entrepreneur (noting that business expenses are not normally allowable against income in the M-E regime in any event)?

How will the eventual granting of a Carte (or Titre) de Séjour (residency card) impact the ability of the resident to eventually monetise their content on YouTube?

Comment: Surely, if you are ‘monetising’ something, you are *earning income* from it?

Comment: The question is about the legality of monetising a YT channel in the context of a long stay visitor visa and if it is considered "employment" per se and thus against the conditions of the Visa.